# Python: How to connect to a protected svn repository with setuptools

Tags: python, svn, setuptools

I am trying to configure a setuptools.setup script. PyPI packages works fine but I don't manage to install the 'mypackage' module from my svn repository. I get the error:

*Couldn't find index page for 'myotherpackage' (maybe misspelled?)*

- Did I forget something important concerning the dependency_links parameter?
- Are the provided parameters (see below) ok?

## setup.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from setuptools import setup, find_packages
version = '2.5'

setup(name='myotherpackage',
      description='My main package called myotherpackage',
      packages=find_packages(),
      version=version,
      zip_safe=False,
      include_package_data=True,
      install_requires=['nose','tweepy','myotherpackage'],
      dependency_links=['https://code.myrep.net/svn/experimenta/user/myotherpackage/'],
      test_suite='nose.collector', 
      test_require = 'nose',
      )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to add to add some information (`#egg=myotherpackage`) on the end of the dependency_links url, like this:

```
dependency_links=['https://code.myrep.net/svn/experimenta/user/myotherpackage/#egg=myotherpackage'],
```

This is so that setuptools knows what it is downloading.

I tried it with a modified version of your file, replacing your svn link with one I found on the Internet:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from setuptools import setup, find_packages
version = '2.5'

setup(name='myotherpackage',
      description='My main package called myotherpackage',
      packages=find_packages(),
      version=version,
      zip_safe=False,
      include_package_data=True,
      install_requires=['nose','tweepy','setuptools-dev06'],
      # works
      dependency_links=['http://svn.python.org/projects/sandbox/branches/setuptools-0.6/#egg=setuptools-dev06'],
      # doesn't work
      #dependency_links=['http://svn.python.org/projects/sandbox/branches/setuptools-0.6/'],
      test_suite='nose.collector',
      test_require = 'nose',
      )
```

This worked for me. When I comment out the line with the `#egg=setuptools-dev06`, and uncomment the line that just ends with a / , that doesn't work.

Comment: FYI, if using pip, the version number seems to need to be a number (so `dev06` doesn't work)