# Python setuptools: How can I list a private repository under install_requires?

Tags: python, github, setuptools

I am creating a `setup.py` file for a project which depends on private GitHub repositories.  The relevant parts of the file look like this:

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(name='my_project',
    ...,
    install_requires=[
        'public_package',
        'other_public_package',
        'private_repo_1',
        'private_repo_2',
    ],
    dependency_links=[
        'https://github.com/my_account/private_repo_1/master/tarball/',
        'https://github.com/my_account/private_repo_2/master/tarball/',
    ],
    ...,
)
```

I am using `setuptools` instead of `distutils` because the latter does not support the `install_requires` and `dependency_links` arguments per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9810603/adding-install-requires-to-setup-py-when-making-a-python-package) answer.

The above setup file fails to access the private repos with a 404 error - which is to be expected since GitHub returns a 404 to unauthorized requests for a private repository.  However, I can't figure out how to make `setuptools` authenticate.

Here are some things I've tried:

1. Use `git+ssh://` instead of `https://` in `dependency_links` as I would if installing the repo with `pip`.  This fails because setuptools doesn't recognize this protocol ("unknown url type: git+ssh"), though the [distribute documentation](http://pythonhosted.org/distribute/setuptools.html#dependencies-that-aren-t-in-pypi) says it should.  Ditto `git+https` and `git+http`.
2. `https://<username>:<password>@github.com/...` - still get a 404.  (This method doesn't work with `curl` or `wget` from the command line either - though `curl -u <username> <repo_url> -O <output_file_name>` does work.)
3. Upgrading setuptools (0.9.7) and virtualenv (1.10) to the latest versions.  Also tried installing distribute though [this overview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344076/differences-between-distribute-distutils-setuptools-and-distutils2) says it was merged back into setuptools.  Either way, no dice.

Currently I just have `setup.py` print out a warning that the private repos must be downloaded separately.  This is obviously less than ideal.  I feel like there's something obvious that I'm missing, but can't think what it might be. :)

Duplicate-ish question with no answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12956168/python-how-to-connect-to-a-protected-svn-repository-with-setuptools).

Answer (score 106, accepted):

I was trying to get this to work for installing with pip, but the above was not working for me. From [1] I understood the `PEP508` standard should be used, from [2] I retrieved an example which actually does work (at least for my case).

Please note; this is with `pip 20.0.2` on `Python 3.7.4`

```
setup(
    name='<package>',
...
    install_requires=[
        '<normal_dependency>',
         # Private repository
        '<dependency_name> @ git+ssh://git@github.com/<user>/<repo_name>@<branch>',
         # Public repository
        '<dependency_name> @ git+https://github.com/<user>/<repo_name>@<branch>',
    ],
)
```

After specifying my package this way installation works fine (also with `-e` settings and without the need to specify `--process-dependency-links`).

**References**
[1] https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4187
[2] https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5566

Comment: If you use `ssh://` and run into `Could not resolve hostname` change the `:` to `/` in your clone url. I had this error with gitlab.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work anymore as setuptools seems to look for a package on PyPi with the dependency name: `Reading https://pypi.org/simple/some-fake-name/`, and then `Couldn't find index page for 'some_fake_name' (maybe misspelled?)`. In the end, the last error displayed is `error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('some_fake_name@ git+ssh://git@github.com/cglacet/quadtree.git')`

Comment: Emphasis that <dependency_name> is not the same as the <repo_name> AND you may replace 'ssh://git@' with 'https://' if it is a public repo

Comment: @Anusha Sorry, I am not able to reproduce cglacet's error. His/her repository is not private and I expect Phil's suggestion to resolve it. Have you tried Phil's suggestion?

Comment: @TomHemmes I am trying to install a local package, so in `install_requires` I have `<package-name> @ file://localhost/lib/<package-name>/<package_name>.version.whl` and I get the same error as @cglacet

Comment: warning!!!! when you pip upgrade,  it seems that even the branch is moving to some new commit,   pip regard them as satisfy! I have posted a question here  [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65969279/pip-install-upgrade-fail-to-upgrade-private-dependency)

Comment: To add a bit more info on  @delijati comment, the SSH URL that is given by Gitlab is not interpretable because it has `:` that separates the domain name from the group `com:<group>`.
Eg : `git@gitlab.<your_org>.com:<group>/<project>.git` to be replaced by  `git@gitlab.<your_org>.com/<group>/<project>.git`

Answer (score 45):

Here's what worked for me:

```
  install_requires=[
      'private_package_name==1.1',
  ],
  dependency_links=[
      'git+ssh://git@github.com/username/private_repo.git#egg=private_package_name-1.1',
  ]
```

Note that you have to have the version number in the egg name, otherwise it will say it can't find the package.

Comment: Hi vadimg - Which version of setuptools/distribute are you using?  I get "Unknown url type: git+ssh" using distribute 0.7.3 (the latest version).

Comment: This did not work for me 3 years later... Got: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement

Comment: As of Oct 28, 2016, this approach seems broken

Comment: It works for me with `pip==9.0.1` and `setuptools==34.3.1` after I set the same version number in `install_requires` and `dependency_links`. But it seems only work when I run `python setup.py install`, not working on wheels and eggs with pip install.

Comment: With modern pip's you need to include an option, something like `pip install --process-dependency-links ...`

Comment: This also works with HTTPS: `git+https://github.com/<company or username>/private_repo.git#egg=private_package-0.0.1` Of course, it will prompt for password (unless it is stored in a keyring). It also requires `--process-dependency-links` option if installing via pip.

Comment: `--process-dpendency-links` is deprecated, see my answer using PEP508 url specification

Comment: I have the following error: `unknown url type: git+ssh ` or `unknown url type: git+https` (Python 3.7)

Answer (score 11):

I couldn't find any good documentation on this, but came across the solution mainly through trial & error. Further, installing from pip & setuptools have some subtle differences; but this way should work for both.

GitHub don't (currently, as of August 2016) offer an easy way to get the zip / tarball of private repos. So you need to point setuptools to tell setuptools that you're pointing to a git repo:

```
from setuptools import setup
import os
# get deploy key from https://help.github.com/articles/git-automation-with-oauth-tokens/
github_token = os.environ['GITHUB_TOKEN']

setup(
    # ...
    install_requires='package',
    dependency_links = [
    'git+https://{github_token}@github.com/user/{package}.git/@{version}#egg={package}-0'
        .format(github_token=github_token, package=package, version=master)
        ]
```

A couple of notes here:

- For private repos, you need to authenticate with GitHub; the simplest way I found is to create an oauth token, drop that into your environment, and then include it with the URL
- You need to include *some* version number (here is `0`) at the end of the link, even if there's no package on PyPI. This has to be a actual number, not a word.
- You need to preface with `git+` to tell setuptools it's to clone the repo, rather than pointing at a zip / tarball
- `version` can be a branch, a tag, or a commit hash
- You need to supply `--process-dependency-links` if installing from pip

Comment: I am getting a cannot find tag or branch message. Despite the fact that the private repo I am attempting to clone does have a tag.

Comment: figured out what the problem was. The tag had a `v` prepended to it in github. So I needed to use `v1.1.0` instead of `1.1.0` in my setup.py script.

Answer (score 5):

I found a (hacky) workaround:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from setuptools import setup
import os

os.system('pip install git+https://github-private.corp.com/user/repo.git@master')

setup( name='original-name'
     , ...
     , install_requires=['repo'] )
```

I understand that there are ethical issues with having a system call in a setup script, but I can't think of another way to do this.

Comment: yes this was also an ugly workaround for us due to the following: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/2822

Comment: This is the only way I could get it to work, although I went with `import pip`. Neither @vadimg's answer or [this suggestion in pypa/pip](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/2124) worked.

Comment: This will install a dependency even if running something unrelated to installation like `python setup.py --version`.

Answer (score 4):

Via Tom Hemmes' answer I found this is the only thing that worked for me:

```
    install_requires=[
        '<package> @ https://github.com/<username>/<package>/archive/<branch_name>.zip']
```

Answer (score 1):

Using archive URL from github works for me, for public repositories. E.g.

```
dependency_links = [
  'https://github.com/username/reponame/archive/master.zip#egg=eggname-version',
]
```

Comment: How do you find the `eggname-version`?

Answer (score 1):

With pip 20.1.1, this works for me

```
install_requires=[ "packson3@https://tracinsy.ewi.tudelft.nl/pubtrac/Utilities/export/138/packson3/dist/packson3-1.0.0.tar.gz"],
```

in setup.py

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way (free):

1. Clone GitHub Repo to GitLab Repo (free account) [link](https://gitlab.com/import/github/status)
2. Add GitLab Repo Access Key (read only) [repository -> settings -> access tokens]
3. Use as dependency: `https://oauth2:GITLAB_ACCESS_TOKEN>@gitlab.com/<GITLAB_USERNAME>/<PROJECT_NAME>.git`

---

**Q&A:**

Q: Why through GitLab?
A: Because GitHub only has Account Access Keys, GitLab has Repository Access Keys!

Q: Access Tokens in git history?
A: Yes, because the whole point is to use a privat repo in privat context, the token is read-only, and the token expires after maximum of 1 year.

Q: Why is the GitLab Repository not synced automatically with the GitHub Repo?
A: Mirroring is a GitLab premium feature, but you can do it for free if you use GitHub Actions, here is a [tutorial](https://dev.to/brunorobert/github-and-gitlab-sync-44mn).

Answer (score -1):

Edit: This appears to only work with public github repositories, see comments.

```
dependency_links=[
    'https://github.com/my_account/private_repo_1/tarball/master#egg=private_repo_1',
    'https://github.com/my_account/private_repo_2/tarball/master#egg=private_repo_2',
],
```

Above syntax seems to work for me with setuptools 1.0. At the moment at least the syntax of adding "#egg=project_name-version" to VCS dependencies is documented in the link you gave to [distribute documentation](http://pythonhosted.org/distribute/setuptools.html#dependencies-that-aren-t-in-pypi).

Comment: I still get the same 404 error.  Are the repos in your case private?  I am aware of the #egg= syntax but don't know that it affects authentication.

Comment: Sorry, it of course was a public repo project. There probably is not any way to do this with current setuptools if https//<username>:<password>@... tarball URLs don't work with githubs private repositories as this question seems also to indicate: [having-trouble-downloading-git-archive-tarballs-from-private-repo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10046027/having-trouble-downloading-git-archive-tarballs-from-private-repo)

Comment: You could try also development version of setuptools and/or check the code. The
relevant code seems to be:
[package_index:fetch_distribution():534](https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/src/9f475ec7aedd04ccf89483d8575808d30e31ab51/setuptools/package_index.py?at=default#cl-534)
[package_index.py:_download_url():736](https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/src/9f475ec7aedd04ccf89483d8575808d30e31ab51/setuptools/package_index.py?at=default#cl-736)

Answer (score -2):

This work for our scenario:

1. package is on github in a private repo
2. we want to install it into site-packages (not into ./src with -e)
3. being able to use pip install -r requirements.txt
4. being able to use pip install -e reposdir (or from github), where the dependencies are only specified in requirements.txt

https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3610#issuecomment-356687173