# pip install private package

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I have one python package A which has depends on another private package named godot(hosted at bitbucket, and should be accessed by  git+ssh protocol). In package A's setup.py, I have following code:

```
...
install_requires=['godot'],
dependency_links=['git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/xxx/godot.git#egg=godot']
...
```

I have two questions here:

1. Now setuptools 1.4 (latest stable version)  does not support 'git+ssh' protocol, only code in the development branch handle this protocol: [Python setuptools: How can I list a private repository under install_requires?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18026980/python-setuptools-how-can-i-list-a-private-repository-under-install-requires#comment27433425_18563923). I have installed the development version via:

   `pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall hg+https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools#egg=setuptools`

   I almost solved this bit, but I wonder If any other approach available? Invoke pip install -r requirements.txt(have **git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/xxx/godot.git#egg=godot** list in requirements.txt)?
2. The second question is name conflict. There is another package on pypi also named godot, So when I install package A using follow command, pip install the godot from pypi index:

   `pip install git+ssh://git@pypi.corp.com/xxx/A.git#egg=A`

   How could force pip(setup.py) to install the private godot package, rather than the one on pypi index?

Answer (score 1):

For part 1: you can install packages via pip by specifying as:

```
$ pip install http://my.package.repo/SomePackage-1.0.4.zip
```

To keep it simple and avoid spending undue time on it, I would just download the `.zip` source file and install via pip as above.

See [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install.html#pip-install-examples)...

For part 2: pip has a `--no-dependencies` switch. Add that after installing all the dependencies manually

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old topic, but it might help people coming across it through google search:

Actually, for part 2, you can simply define the package adress inside the install_requires part:

```
...
install_requires=['godot @ git+ssh://bitbucket.org/xxx/godot.git#egg=godot']
...
```