# How to include a git repo as a dependency when using pbr

Tags: python, git, python-pbr

I'm using [pbr](https://docs.openstack.org/pbr/latest/) which uses a `requirements.txt` file to look for dependencies.

I've a line in `requirements.txt` like `git+ssh://git@github.com/user/repo.git` and it works when I run `pip install -r requirements.txt`

However, when I run `python setup.py build` I run in to the error:

```
error in setup command: 'install_requires' must be a string or list of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers; Invalid requirement, parse error at "'+ssh://g'"
```

There are [many Stack Overflow answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18026980/python-setuptools-how-can-i-list-a-private-repository-under-install-requires) that deal with this problem exclusively when using `setuptools` and all of them suggest putting the Git dependency into the `dependency_links` list in `setup.py`.

I would like pbr to be able to deal with my Git dependency directly from `requirements.txt` in a way that works when I run both `python setup.py build` and `pip install -r requirements.txt`.

Is this possible? Are there any close workarounds?

Answer (score 2):

In the example you provided, pbr is propagating the whole line to install_requires, which produces an invalid line.

#### Provide the requirement name via #egg=name

For it to work as intended, the url needs a `#egg` suffix to tell pbr what requirement is provided by that URL. If the URL looks like this, pbr will [scrape a requirement](https://github.com/openstack-dev/pbr/blob/4.0.4/pbr/packaging.py#L135-L147) out of the `#egg` part and propagate only `repo` to `install_requires`:

```
git+ssh://git@github.com/user/repo.git#egg=repo
```

#### Version constraints

If a version is included, [pbr will add](https://github.com/openstack-dev/pbr/blob/4.0.4/pbr/packaging.py#L104-L110) a `>=` constraint on it. So this would become `repo>=1.2.3` in `install_requires`:

```
git+ssh://git@github.com/user/repo.git#egg=repo-1.2.3
```

#### Dependency Links

It'll also [extract a dependency_link item](https://github.com/openstack-dev/pbr/blob/4.0.4/pbr/packaging.py#L178-L180) that contains the full URL. You can use it by passing `--process-dependency-links` to pip. By default, pip will return the error `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement repo` unless the package is also available via PyPI. If `--process-dependency-links` is specified, then it'll fetch it from the Git URL instead.

#### Use the -e flag, or require `pbr>=1.9.0`

Prior to version 1.9.0, pbr only recognized `http` and `https` URLs, unless the line started with `-e`. It added support for `git://`, `git+ssh://`, `git+https://` without `-e` in [this commit](https://github.com/openstack-dev/pbr/commit/31a0e97cbff495401ab7ded498b680e1f918153c).