# Where are install_requires names coming from?

Tags: python, pygame, setuptools

Recently, I installed a package that requires Pygame learning environment: https://github.com/ntasfi/PyGame-Learning-Environment

I added 'ple' to my install_requires, but got this error despite PyGame-Learning-Environment being successfully installed:

```
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ple (from MonsterKong-RandomEnsemble==0.0.1) (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for ple (from MonsterKong-RandomEnsemble==0.0.1)
```

Comment: The project was not uploaded to pypi.org where `pip` and `easy_install` look for packages to download and install by default. If you want the package to be declared as a dependency in the setup script, you will need to specify the link to download the package from; check out this question for more details: [Python setuptools: How can I list a private repository under install_requires?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18026980/python-setuptools-how-can-i-list-a-private-repository-under-install-requires)

Answer (score 0):

Check for other `MonsterKong-RandomEnsemble` versions and also check if your spelling for the distribution name is correct

Comment: theres no other versions of Monsterkong-randomensemble

Comment: yes my question was how do you know the right distribution name? To import that distribtion, you use "ple" so i assume thats the right name