# pip install upgrade fail to upgrade private dependency

Tags: python, pip

background: pip support ssh link suffix with

1. branch name,
2. a commit hash,
3. a tag name
4. a git ref

However, pip has a problem in upgrade some package depends on these ssh links.

in a setup.py of a package called CurrentPackage that is version 5.1.2

```
install_requires=[
    "MyOwnPackage @ git+ssh://git@github.com/myusename/MyOwnPackage@master",
],
```

i then pip install --upgrade -e .

```
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: 
MyOwnPackage@git+ssh://git@github.com/myusename/MyOwnPackage@master from 
git+ssh://****@github.com/myusename/MyOwnPackage@master in 
/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from CurrentPackage==5.1.2) (0.0.1)
```

The master branch is already 0.0.2.
It clearly didn't upgrade MyOwnPackage to the new master branch commit, still staying at 0.0.1.

Comment: 1. first of all, you are not referring to the question.        2. Secondly, specifying the version is a common practice, tons of python setup.py require a specific version of the dependency.

Comment: Sure, but VCS (git, etc.) are special cases. You can not specify a version number, but you can specify a git tag, or a git commit instead.

Comment: @sinoroc thanks for pointing it out. I am editing my question.

Answer (score 1):

pip does not check if a remote reference has been changed between installs. This means that pointing to a moving reference (like you have here) does not work as expected.

I'd suggest using:

- specific commit hashes or tags, that are modified when you want to make upgrades
- invoking pip with --upgrade to tell it to look around eagerly.
- convert these packages into proper distributions and use --find-links or --index-url with that.

Comment: --upgrade is already used.  I dont want to use eager since it upgrade everything to latest version. the default only-if-needed is enough.

Comment: @LukAron Seems to me like these are `OR` suggestions. Use one of the 3 (or maybe combinations of the 3). But I would think that setting a specific (non-moving) git commit or git tag should be enough, no need to force with `--upgrade` on top of that.

Comment: @sinoroc seems that  git commit or git tag doesn't work too, I later update the question

Comment: In your question you seem to use `master`. Typically this is a branch, more or less it is a moving reference (i.e. it does not always point at the same commit), so I would not recommend this. You really should use a non-moving reference such as a specific git commit hash or a git tag. -- Now I am not sure what you mean by "doesn't work". -- pip most likely sees that it already cloned and installed `master`, so why should it do it again?

Answer (score -1):

Ok , I conclude that it is
**pathetic** to list the private dependency in setup.py
since the syntax must be

```
packagename @ git+ssh://git@github.com/myusename/packagename
```

simply put

```
-e git+ssh://git@github.com/myusename/MyOwnPackage==0.0.2
```

in requirements.txt