# Setup.py reinstalling already installed user-written package

Tags: python, git, pip, setuptools, setup.py

I am developing two python packages, `pkg_a` and `pkg_b`. `pkg_a` is a requirement for `pkg_b`, and so the `setup.py` for `pkg_b` looks like this:

```
from setuptools import setup

inst_reqs = [
    'pkg_a @ git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/vlad/pkg_a.git',
]

setup(
    name="pkg_b",
    version="0.0.0",
    packages=['pkg_b'],
    install_requires=inst_reqs,
)
```

Since I am developing both packages simultaneously, `pkg_a` is already installed in editable mode (`pip install -e .`).

When pip installing `pkg_b`, why is the existing installation of `pkg_a` removed? It looks like pip will systematically cone the specified repo, uninstall the existing `pkg_a` and reinstall it from the cloned repo:

```
Successfully built pkg_a
Installing collected packages: pkg_a, pkg_b
  Attempting uninstall: pkg_a
    Found existing installation: pkg_a 0.0.0
    Uninstalling pkg_a-0.0.0:
      Successfully uninstalled pkg_a-0.0.0
  Running setup.py develop for pkg_b
Successfully installed pkg_a-0.0.0 pkg_b
```

I'm guessing this has to with versioning but I don't know how to fix this. Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is how VCS dependencies are handled. You should specify a fixed reference (tag, commit id):

```
'pkg_a @ git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/vlad/pkg_a.git@da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709'
```

See: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#git

If you do not specific a fixed reference (non-moving tag, or commit ID), then pip has to clone every time since the content of the repository might have changed since the last installation.

*(To be honest, even after this change, it might still be that *pip* will re-clone at each installation, I do not remember the exact behavior off the top of my head.)*

See similar question: [pip install upgrade fail to upgrade private dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65969279/pip-install-upgrade-fail-to-upgrade-private-dependency)

Comment: Also, an editable install will be replaced more "easily".  I cannot remember the details, but I suspect that if you installed `pkg_a` normally, then it might not be re-installed each time.

Comment: Sinoroc's answer is correct, you should accept it.  :)